# Chopping Unicode Bytes

Tags: code-golf, string, unicode

## Introduction

Each Unicode codepoint can be represented as a sequence of up to 4 bytes. Because of this, it is possible to interpret some 2, 3, or 4-byte characters as multiple 1-byte characters. (See [here](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/%7Erichard/utf-8.html) for a UTF-8 to bytes converter).

## Challenge

Given a UTF-8 character, output it split into a sequence of 1-byte characters. If the character is 1-byte already, return it unchanged.

- Your program must take one, and exactly one, UTF-8 character as input. You may use any input method you wish, as long as it has been decided on meta that is is a valid method. You cannot take input as a bytearray or series of bytes; then the challenge would just be converting hex to ASCII.
- Your program must output one or more ASCII 1-byte characters. Again, any output method is allowed as long as it has been marked valid on meta. Edit: As per the conversation in the comments, output should be in Code Page 850.

Note: see [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for valid I/O methods.

## Example I/O

> `܀ (0x700)`
> `▄Ç (0xdc 0x80)`
>
> `a (0x61)`
> `a (0x61)`
>
> `聂 (0x8042)`
> `Þüé (0xe8 0x81 0x82)`

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: It looks like the hex values in the output examples map to the hex byte values of the split input, but I don't know where the actual output characters are coming from. I checked extended ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, Unicode...

Comment: Can we input as a byte array (obviously allowed input method for a string) and output as a byte array (obviously allowed output method for a string)? :)

Comment: Could you explain the splitting? How does the two byte number `0x8042` split into the three bytes `0xe8, 0x81, 0x82` for example?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I believe `0x8042` is the codepoint of the character, which translates to those bytes  in UTF-8

Comment: @JoKing "translates" how? Should be in the question IMO...

Comment: @JoKing Hmmm - "Your program must take one, and exactly one, UTF-8 character as input" - if we can take that as bytes then this is just "convert to chars", and if we can output those chars as bytes it's a no-op :/

Comment: I believe the characters are taken from [this image](http://www.asciitable.com/index/extend.gif) from asciitable.com (warning, there's like 20 ads on the page), though I have no idea what encoding it is

Comment: @JoKing Do you mean [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)?

Comment: There are a lot of things about this question that need clarification. There's no such thing as a "UTF-8 codepoint"; maybe you meant a Unicode codepoint? Moreover, in UTF-8, it's *not* possible to interpret a 2-, 3-, or 4-byte character as multiple 1-byte characters. Moreover, given a Unicode character, it's not possible to "split [it] into a sequence of 1-byte characters," so you should clarify what you mean by that. Moreover, you say that the output must be "ASCII 1-byte characters" even though the vast majority of Unicode characters are impossible to represent as ASCII characters.

Comment: Moreover, you say that the input is "a UTF-8 character," but in the examples you list, the input characters are not in UTF-8. Moreover, since you wrote "1-byte characters" and not "bytes," and since the example outputs are given in the form of character, it sounds like you're asking us to apply a character encoding to the output, but it's not clear which one we're supposed to use—you say ASCII, but that encoding isn't possible to use, and the examples don't use it.

Comment: I'm **guessing** that you're asking us to take a Unicode codepoint as a number and output its UTF-8 representation as a sequence of bytes, but that's only a guess. Is that right?

Comment: @tsh The third example, featuring  Þ at 0xE8, suggests [Code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), but nice pick indeed!

Comment: @TannerSwett - yes, you must take a unicode codepoint and output it as a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @sugarfi With the tool at http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.html, your first example (܀) turns into Ü <80>, as the tool relies on ISO-8859-1 rather than code page 850. ISO-8859-1 features no printable char at 0x80. Do you code under DOS ?

Comment: @Nacre - funny, I looked up "ASCII 128" and the result was the character above.

Comment: Funny, I look up ["ASCII 128"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+128) and the  first result tells me "The ASCII table has 128 characters, with values from 0 through 127". You are going to have to specify which one byte code page you are talking about

Comment: As far as I understand that's the only thing holding this challenge up. Which code page should the output be in? Based on your example, @Nacre seems to be correct with code page 850. So either say "It's code page 850" or update the question and example to be something else (like UTF-8)

Comment: @Malivil - will do.

Comment: I have updated my answer to conform to the confirmed code page

Comment: The UTF-8 to bytes converter that you link in your question doesnt use CP850, I think it would be better to say that you can output the codepoint e.g. `0x80` if CP850 is not supported by your language.

Comment: If the input is the code point, and the output is a series of bytes, then what is the point of specifying the output encoding?

Comment: I'm not sure, people on this stream asked me to so i did

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>73</s> 85 bytes

```cs
a=>Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a).Select(b=>Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetString(new[]{b}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXruPpmleam1qUmJSTChWys1NIs/2faGvnmpecnwIU0AsNcbPQc08tcaosSS3WSNTUC07NSU0u0UhCUgOUhrE1LEwNNEECwWDzNPJSy6Njq5NqNTX/W3M55@cV5@ek6oUXZZak@mTmpWpAbNUDSiQnlmikaSjdaVDS1NQkSmki0SpfNDaB1f4HAA)

+12 bytes to use the updated code page